# maxHeight for onyx.Menu not working properly in enyo

Tags: menu, enyo

Hey I'm having a problem with menus in my enyo app. Basically, maxHeight isn't doing anything on it. I cut my code down to emphasize just the problem:

```
enyo.kind({
name: "App",
fit: true,
components:[
    {kind: "onyx.MenuDecorator", components: [
        {name: "firstMonthContent", content: "Month"},
        {name: "firstMonth", kind: "onyx.Menu", maxHeight: 200, onSelect: "getFirstMonth", components: [
                {value: "0", content: "Jan", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "1", content: "Feb", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "2", content: "Mar", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "3", content: "Apr", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "4", content: "May", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "5", content: "Jun", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "6", content: "Jul", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "7", content: "Aug", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "8", content: "Sep", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "9", content: "Oct", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "10", content: "Nov", classes: "menuItem"},
                {value: "11", content: "Dec", classes: "menuItem"},
        ]}
    ]},
],
});
```

Just a basic menu, everything works fine except for the maxHeight. Problem is, when I put this into jsfiddle, it works completely fine ( http://jsfiddle.net/sqHSL/17/ ). I created a new enyo file that has only this in it and it still causes this problem so I'm not sure what to do to fix it. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out the actual reason but I did figure out a work-around.

```
                {kind: "onyx.MenuDecorator", maxHeight: "5px", components: [
                    {name: "firstMonthContent", content: "Month"},
                    {name: "firstMonth", kind: "onyx.Menu", onSelect: "getFirstMonth", components: [
                        {name: "menuScroller2", kind: "enyo.Scroller", defaultKind: "onyx.MenuItem", vertical: "auto", classes: "enyo-unselectable", maxHeight: "200px", components: [
                            {value: "0", content: "Jan", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "1", content: "Feb", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "2", content: "Mar", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "3", content: "Apr", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "4", content: "May", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "5", content: "Jun", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "6", content: "Jul", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "7", content: "Aug", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "8", content: "Sep", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "9", content: "Oct", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "10", content: "Nov", classes: "menuItem"},
                            {value: "11", content: "Dec", classes: "menuItem"},
                        ]}
                    ]}
                ]},
```